# Leetcode 110. Balanced Binary Tree Can I ask why my solution is wrong?

Tags: java, algorithm

The original question is attached here: https://leetcode.com/problems/balanced-binary-tree/description/

```
public class BalancedBinaryTree {

    static boolean balance = true;

    public boolean isBalanced(TreeNode root) {
        if (root == null)
            return true;
        return (Math.abs(depth(root.left) - depth(root.right)) <= 1) && balance;
    }

    public int depth(TreeNode root) {
        if (balance) {
            if (root == null)
                return 0;

            int lengthOfLeft = depth(root.left);
            int lengthOfRight = depth(root.right);

            if (Math.abs(lengthOfLeft - lengthOfRight) > 1) {
                balance = false;
            }
            return Math.max(lengthOfLeft, lengthOfRight) + 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What **language** is your code in? Please add the relevant language tag to your question.

Comment: You should probably post this in: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: int lengthOfLeft will always be 0. You should add previous value also, don't you think?

Comment: How do you know it's wrong in the first place? Haven't you run some tests to see if your code works as expected? If not, then do that, and use the results to draw some conclusions. Use your debugger to step through your code.

Comment: @LingboTang His code isn't currently functioning, so it's not under the purview of code review.

Comment: You could look at: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-determine-if-a-binary-tree-is-balanced/ as reference.  You can click on the `java` tab.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
"my solution is wrong" is not a problem specification.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Basically, you should have been reseting the balance back to true, because going from a test where the output is positive (expect true) to one where it is negative (expect false) will matter.

```
 static boolean balance = true;

public boolean isBalanced(TreeNode root) {
    balance = true;
    if (root == null)
        return true;
    return (Math.abs(depth(root.left) - depth(root.right)) <= 1) && balance;
}

public int depth(TreeNode root) {
    if (balance) {
        if (root == null)
            return 0;

        int lengthOfLeft = depth(root.left);
        int lengthOfRight = depth(root.right);

        if (Math.abs(lengthOfLeft - lengthOfRight) > 1) {
            balance = false;
        }
        return Math.max(lengthOfLeft, lengthOfRight) + 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah. Yes. Nice catch. Genius. This "bug" is not really so obvious

Comment: Thank you :) It occurred to me when I used a debugger in eclipse with a few tests. Interesting question